# Random text on top of header in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel. The problem is there is a character "c" on top of the header. When I look through all my template files, there is no "c". I can't seem to find which file is outputting this text "c".

[image]

Comment: Is it showing on all the pages?

Comment: Are you using laravel 5.0 framework?

Comment: try to look in the controller which is rendering the view and the function from which you passed it.

Comment: are you using blades? then try clearing cached blade files.

Comment: Im using laravel 5.3. Yes, it is showing on all pages and im using blades.

Comment: Clearing the cache blade files doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Find This Files:-

home (resources/views/home.blade.php)
layouts.app (resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Comment: Thank you. I checked these files and they dont have the text "c". Forgot to mention that it is output on all pages.